# PLT redirection and dlsym

Tags: c, linux, redirect, elf

I want to redirect a few functions in an arbitrary program and be able to call the old functions in the new functions. I use hotpatch to inject my shared library and PLT redirection seems to be the way to go.

But what about symbols, the program receives with dlsym? They don't seem to have any PLT entry, so how do you redirect those?

Is there a library which does what I want to do?

Comment: You can try to hook `dlsym` itself, because values returned by it are just pointers to a memory region assigned to a shared library loaded by `dlopen()`, it's very hard to replace all pointers with your values.

Comment: But then some stubs must be generated to redirect calls to the memorized function pointers, that's a problem.

Comment: The injection can happen at any time so the program may have called dlsym already. What exactly does dlsym return?